# Questions about running GUI programs through cockpit package

Tags: linux, gui, cockpit

I installed and activated cockpit. The next task is to visit port 9090 on the server, and the cockpit is executed, but I don't understand what it means to visit port 9090 on the server. If you know it, please reply
For your information, I'm using centos8.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run GUI programs through cockpit. Its a webgui for underlying services like imagebuilder and so on. You would either want to use X forwarding within a SSH session or some remote desktop solution like VNC.

Those are the available plugins for a RedHat9:

```
[root@rhel92-baseimage ~]# yum search cockpit
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:06 ago on Thu 15 Jun 2023 10:46:16 AM CEST.
=========================================================== Name Exactly Matched: cockpit ============================================================
cockpit.x86_64 : Web Console for Linux servers
========================================================== Name & Summary Matched: cockpit ===========================================================
cockpit-bridge.x86_64 : Cockpit bridge server-side component
cockpit-composer.noarch : Composer GUI for use with Cockpit
cockpit-doc.noarch : Cockpit deployment and developer guide
cockpit-file-sharing.noarch : Cockpit user interface for managing SMB and NFS file sharing.
cockpit-machines.noarch : Cockpit user interface for virtual machines
cockpit-navigator.noarch : A File System Browser for Cockpit
cockpit-packagekit.noarch : Cockpit user interface for packages
cockpit-pcp.x86_64 : Cockpit PCP integration
cockpit-podman.noarch : Cockpit component for Podman containers
cockpit-session-recording.noarch : Cockpit Session Recording
cockpit-storaged.noarch : Cockpit user interface for storage, using udisks
cockpit-system.noarch : Cockpit admin interface package for configuring and troubleshooting a system
cockpit-ws.x86_64 : Cockpit Web Service
```